# Is there a Windows window flag utility with set capability?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to get and set window flags on existing Windows NT 'window objects'.
I found a similar tool named [A Tool to look up Common Windows Flags](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1856/A-Tool-to-look-up-Common-Windows-Flags) but it focuses to `decode flags into individual values`. To modify these values seem non-systematic but documented. Is there a tool that does this?